# Broadcast receiver not triggered after app is stopped

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, activity-lifecycle

I have a broadcast receiver defined in the manifest with the android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED in the intent filter.

It's triggered fine when the app is in the stack, but after I stop it from android settings it won't trigger anymore. any suggestions?

Update for Menny:

```
<receiver android:name=".auto.AppLauncher">
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Can you add more information? Like snippet from the AndroidManifest where you declared the filter, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Did you program a BroadcastReceiver in your Code?

```
    public class receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED)) {
                    //something you want to do here
            }
        }
    }
```